# Get length of a list inside of a list with dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am pretty new to Python and I am currently working with json files. My task is to **write a universal code that finds the length of the longest list and if there is none inside it should simply return 0.**
My list is:

```
data= [{'foos': [{'prop1': 'value1', 'prop2': 'value2'},
           {'prop1': 'value3', 'prop2': 'value4'}]}]
```

What I have done for counting the lists is this:

```
jd= json.dumps(data)
print(jd)

def long(x):
    counter=-1
    length=0
    for i in x:
        print(i)
        if "[" in i:
            print(i)
            counter+=1
            return counter
        if "[" not in i:
            counter=counter
    return counter
long(data)
```

which returns 1 accordingly to my data
The problem is trying to find the length of this list, which should be something like this

```
len([{'prop1': 'value1', 'prop2': 'value2'},
       {'prop1': 'value3', 'prop2': 'value4'}])
```

Is there a way to get the length of this list? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that `len` is not the way to get the length of a list.

Comment: I also don't understand what you were intending to achieve with the `long` function but I think you won't need it at all.

Comment: Data is simply one of the inputs I have, but my code should work for every data input. If I have a random data list as an input I need to find out where the list is inside the data and then get the length. This Data is just an example of what I meant with my task. Sry if there was misinformation regarding my question

Comment: Err then why can't you use a dict to show `longestList : listLocation` (so that you can have both the list and it's location), and use `len()` to get the longest? Maybe I have misunderstood your question.